# How to make asp.net mvc3 have split template for desktop version and mobile version like mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I currently developing a website with my team http://www.peoplehope.com using asp.net mvc3, and I want to developing the mobile version for this website. Do I need to make another website to handle the mobile version or I can tweak the desktop code to handle the mobile version.

I have already looking to upgrade it to mvc4 that have this functionality, but I have limited time to develop it, and I affraid if i migrate to mvc 4, my desktop version become broken.

Any suggestion or reference to do this kind of split in mvc3??

Answer (score 2):

If you want just use another Layout you can switch them in your _ViewStart file

```
@{
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice){
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMobile.vbhtml";
    }else{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml";
    }
}
```

If you want change the entire site so, just detect the mobile site the same way and redirect to initial controller of mobile site

to a better answer please, tell us how far you want go, this can be so easy or become more complicated than you think, all depends how far you want go

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade to MVC4 and would like to still get advantage of using `.Mobile` extensions here is a nice approach on how you can use `.Mobile` views for mobile devices

http://kevinmontrose.com/2011/07/17/mobile-views-in-asp-net-mvc3/

This way you will have more control on your views